# PSI HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: 2010, project-server, 403

When I'm trying to get here:

http://someName.com/_vti_bin/PSI/

all I get is the following error: "This website requires you to log in" ..but I'm logged in as Administrator. (and I can get to a specific location e.g. http://someName.com/_vti_bin/PSI/Project.asmx?wsdl)

The problem is that my WebPart, because of that situation, cannot access any PWA WebService.

I think that the issue is related to the server configuration because it doesn't work only on production server - on dev it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Situation has changed. I've tested this on another Admin account and it has worked. I have no idea why because those accounts are identical. What's more if I put my code (on dev server) `wssInterop.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;` in `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` block - it crashes and can't connect to WebService.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior to receive a 403 when browsing to the PSI directory.. probably to prevent just anyone listing files on the server.

You must use the full URL (as you noticed):
`http://server/ProjectServer/_vti_bin/PSI/Project.asmx`

If your webpart cannot access the web service, it is because of a different problem.

I've had success using `new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);` to use credentials for the service acct. You could also try DefaultNetworkCredential but not sure if that will work.